# Is DS-5 supported on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ds-5

I am trying to install DS-5 on my laptop running Windows 10. Does DS-5 support Windows 10? If yes which version should I be using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Status in Nov 2020**

Yes, DS-5 (as of Nov 2020) officially supports Windows 10 (See https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/system-requirements for details).

**Status in Sep 2015**

Version 5.22 (current in Sep 2015) is officially not supported on Windows 10. The page http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/system-requirements/ shows the list of the supported OSes. Having said that, it is likely that certain tools are likely to work on Windows 10. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332642/behavior-of-ds-5-on-a-unsupported-os) for a related answer.