# Behavior of DS-5 on an unsupported OS

Tags: ds-5

I am able to install DS-5 on an OS (for example Windows 10) that is not officially supported. What is the behavior of DS-5 on such an OS? Will it work partially, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DS-5 is a suite of tools, including Eclipse IDE, compilers (ARM compiler 5, ARM compiler 6, gcc), DS-5 debugger, Streamline performance analysis tool.

Though an OS may not be listed as supported, individual tools may be supported. A good example is Mac OS, where Streamline and Eclipse IDE are supported while other tools are not.

The best way to find out if a tool would work is to check the [DS-5 System requirements page](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/system-requirements)